# Showing that if commutative R has infinite strictly ascending chains of principal ideals then so does R[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

[image]

First of all, I don't understand why $f_{i+1}\mid f_i$. If $\left< f_i \right>\subset \left< f_{i+1} \right>$, then wouldn't $f_{i}\mid f_{i+1}$?

Thank you for your help so far. I have one more question. In the proof it says $g$ is not a unit in $R[x]$ because $\left< f_m \right>\subset \left< f_{m+1} \right>$. I don't understand that. Could someone explain? Thank you!

Comment: No, the division is in the right direction. For the ideal to be "big", you want the generator to be "small". E.g. $<1>$ is the full ring. In $Z$, $<2>$ is the set of even numbers, which *contains* $<6>$, the set of numbers divisible by $6$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the explicit question at the end, the divisibility ordering of ring elements corresponds to *reverse* inclusion of the deals they generate.  For example, in $\mathbb Z$, 2 divides 4 and $(4)\subseteq(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\langle f_i \rangle \subset \langle f_{i + 1} \rangle$ then $f_i \in \langle f_{i + 1} \rangle$, and since these are principal ideals, we must have $f_i = gf_{i + 1}$ for some $g \in R[x]$.  Thus $f_{i + 1} \mid f_i$.  ***QED***

***Note added in edit; Sunday 17 November 2013 11:45 PM PST:*** This note addresses the OP's second question.  We have $f_i = gf_{i + 1}$ since $\langle f_i \rangle \subset \langle f_{i + 1} \rangle$, as seen above.  If $g \in R[x]$ were a unit, there would exist $h \in R[x]$, also a unit, such that $gh = hg = 1$.  Then $hf_i = hgf_{i + 1} = f_{i + 1}$, so that $f_{i + 1} \in \langle f_i \rangle$, forcing $\langle f_{i + 1} \rangle \subset \langle f_i \rangle$, forcing $\langle f_{i + 1} \rangle = \langle f_i \rangle$, in contradiction to the stated hypothesis on the chain $\langle f_i \rangle$, that it is strictly increalsing.  ***End:  Note added in edit.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always.

***Fiat Lux!!!***